# Kusto naming columns returned from aggregation

Tags: kql

I've got a super simple query that uses the Percentiles aggregation. Is there any way to name the returned columns? The default uses very long names like "percentile_duration_95", unwieldy in graphs and really any results output. Here's a sample of the simple AppInsights query:

```
requests
| summarize req_count=sum(itemCount), ave_duration=avg(duration), percentiles(duration, 95, 99) by name
| order by ave_duration desc
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could try this:

```
requests
| summarize req_count = sum(itemCount),
            ave_duration = avg(duration),
            (first_name, second_name) = percentiles(duration, 95, 99) // <- replace with your desired names
         by name
| order by ave_duration desc
```